# Why is confidence interval for slope in MLR model returning NA in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

```
model1 <- lm(nutri$Fat~nutri$cCalories+nutri$cFiber+nutri$cCholesterol)
summary(model1)

confint(model1, 'cFiber', level=0.95)
```

Returns:
         2.5 % 97.5 %
cFiber    NA     NA

Why not calculating?
Thank you.

Comment: Very hard to tell with no details of model or data. You are not following usual R procedure of offering a formula with column names that refer to a a data argument. There may not be a term in the `lm` object that matches your `'cFiber'`

Comment: There is NA because no column is named 'cFiber' it is obvious. Just use confint(model1), it will show you the confidence interval for all the variables and "cFiber".

Comment: Thank you MB, that worked.  
Fiber is a column; cFiber is a result of centering that column.